# Python 3 How to remove item from room after adding it to inventory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm not sure what I did incorrectly, (still very much a beginner as far as coding goes), but the `del rooms[currm]['Item']` line doesn't actually delete the item. I followed a guide for most of this but the one I used didn't do a delete item bit. So any help will be appreciated. Using Python 3.

```
 item & direction declaration
item = None
direction = 'direction'


def instructions():
    # print main menu and the commands
    print('\n' + ('\t' * 18) + f'''Evil Sorceress Text Adventure Game\n
                  Collect all 6 items to win the game, or be destroyed by the Evil Sorceress, Daeris.
                  Move commands: 'Go {direction}' (North, South, East, West)
                  Add to Inventory: Get {'Item'}\n\n''')


def prologue():  # story set up
    print('\t\tThe Evil Sorceress, Thalya, has taken over the castle of a neighboring kingdom for her Master:')
    print('\n' + ('\t' * 10) + '\033[1m' + 'The Ultimate Evil.' + '\033[0m\n')
    print('''\t\tIt’s up to you to defeat her and reclaim it for the forces of Good! You’ll enter via the Gatehouse.
        You must Get some Armor from the Guard Room for melee protection.
        An Amulet for magical protection from the Enchanting Room.
        A Spellbook from the Library to take down her magical shield.
        A Torch from the Courtyard to light the room.
        A Sword from the Armory to defeat her.
        And finally a Turkey Leg from the Great Hall because fighting evil on an empty stomach is never a good idea!'''
          '\n')


# room, item and direction assignments
rooms = {'Throne Room': {'South': 'Great Hall', 'Boss': 'Daeris'},
         'Great Hall': {'North': 'Throne Room', 'West': 'Library', 'South': 'Courtyard', 'East': 'Armory',
                        'Item': 'Turkey Leg'},
         'Library': {'East': 'Great Hall', 'Item': 'Spellbook'},
         'Courtyard': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'South': 'Gatehouse', 'East': 'Enchanting Room', 'Item': 'Torch'},
         'Armory': {'West': 'Great Hall', 'South': 'Enchanting Room', 'Item': 'Sword'},
         'Enchanting Room': {'North': 'Armory', 'West': 'Courtyard', 'Item': 'Amulet'},
         'Gatehouse': {'North': 'Courtyard', 'East': 'Guard House', },
         'Guard House': {'West': 'Gatehouse', 'Item': 'Armor'},
         }

inv = []  # assigns inventory variable
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']  # List of vowels
currm = 'Gatehouse'  # Assigns starting room as the Gatehouse
pin = ''  # Returns results of previous input

# prints prologue & instructions
prologue()
input('\n Press any key to continue\n\n')
instructions()

# gameplay loop
while True:
    print(f'\nCurrent Position: {currm}\nInventory : {inv}\n{"~" * 27}')
    print(pin)

    #  Item pickup prompt
    if 'Item' in rooms[currm].keys():
        nitem = rooms[currm]['Item']
        if nitem not in inv:
            if nitem[0] not in vowels:
                print(f"There's an {nitem} here. Take it?\n")
            else:
                print(f"There's a {nitem} here. Take it?\n")

    if 'Boss' in rooms[currm].keys():  # Game End parameters
        if len(inv) == 6:
            print('''Congratulations!
            You've reached the Throne Room and defeated the Evil Sorceress, Daeris.
            And have therefore reclaimed the castle for the forces of Good!!''')
            break
        else:
            print('Daeris has defeated you and The Ultimate Evil is victorious!')
            break

    # Accepts player's move as input
    uin = input('Enter your move:\n')

    # Splits move into words
    move = uin.split(' ')

    # First word is the action
    action = move[0].title()

    # Second word is object or direction
    if len(move) > 1:
        item = move[1:]
        direction = move[1].title()
        item = ' '.join(item).title()

        # Moving between rooms
    if action == 'Go':
        try:
            currm = rooms[currm][direction]
            pin = f'You head {direction}\n'
        except:
            pin = 'INVALID DIRECTION!\n'

            # Picking up items
    elif action == 'Get':
        try:
            if item == rooms[currm]['Item']:
                if item not in inv:
                    inv.append(rooms[currm]['Item'])
                    if item == ['Turkey Leg']:
                        pin = f'{item} obtained! Om nom nom.\n'
                    else:
                        pin = f'{item} obtained!\n'
                else:
                    del rooms[currm]['Item']  # deletes item if already obtained
            else:
                print('No item here')
        except:
            pin = f'That {item} is located elsewhere'
```

Initially picking up the item the result is:

```
Enter your move:
get armor

Current Position: Guard House
Inventory : ['Armor']
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Armor obtained!
```

However if I try and pick up the item again it acts like I never picked it up to begin with and returns the same result. I'm not 100% on what I expected to happen is but basically this is the result I'm wanting.

```
Enter your move:
get armor

No item here
```

I tried moving this back to be in line with `if item == rooms[currm]['Item']:` to see if that was the issue but that didn't work either.

```
else:
                    del rooms[currm]['Item']  # deletes item if already obtained
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre] and (off-site) [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). We do not find the bug for you here; you are expected to try first to analyze what happens, step by step, when the code runs, and identify a *specific* problem, and then figure out the **smallest code necessary** to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I would suggest you try to understand what `del` does to a dict of dict. Minimally, you can construct `d = {"foo": {"bar": 0}}`. Then see what happens if you do `del d["foo"]["bar"]`. Was that your expected behaviour? Otherwise, use `pop` as suggested in the answer below.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pop something off a list or dict, use `pop()`, not `del`

```py
test_dict = {
    "hello": 2,
    "this": 3,
    "is": 5,
    "an": 5,
    "example": 28,
}

new = test_dict.pop("hello")

print(new)
print(test_dict)
```

```
2
{'this': 3, 'is': 5, 'an': 5, 'example': 28}
```

`del` does something completely different: it deletes something from "memory" (It's complicated) in the current scope. Unless you're doing something really advanced with the language (and you won't for the first year of working in it) you don't need `del` and don't need to understand what it does. There will usually be a cleaner way. `pop` is that way in this case.

Honestly, it might be best to read trough some beginner tutorials on [lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) and [dicts](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

I hope that helps. :-)

Comment: `del` *can* be used to remove elements from both dicts and lists, and you are talking about lists but then demonstrating a dict. It also **does not** "delete" anything "from memory"; it only unbinds names. It's also not an advanced tool at all. It is nothing like `delete` in C++ for example. Also, w3schools is a poor source for HTML/CSS/JS (supposedly their specialty) and a worse source for everything else. `del` [is explicitly covered](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) in the tutorial built directly into the official Python documentation.

Comment: +1 regarding "you don't need `del`". I've never found a use case for `del` aside from deleting attributes in class. Even then, you have `delattr`. Everytime I think of using it, I can find a better way.

Comment: 1) I am aware that W3Schools is not that good of a source, but I have found over the years that beginners tend to like their way of explaining things over, for example, the python docs. At this level, that matters the most.
2) I know that `del` technically removes from `__dict__` (which I'd call memory when talking python) and all that. However, I have rarely seen it used correctly in production, and don't think it's controversial to call it a code smell. I was just meaning to steer away from it, I'm sorry I did not properly explain why one should. 3) Corrected the typo, thank you. :-)